# powershell transscript does not work, no sufficient content

Tags: powershell

i have a powershell script with a small gui to convert old .doc files to the new .docx format. to be sure, everything is running fine and all files are being converted, i want to log my script and create a log file, where i can see which files are converted and which files aren't and the reason why not. so i added start-transscript at the begging and stop-transscript at the end. now my problem is, that every action in the script seems to be ignored. when i open the log file, i only see the message except the header "The recording has been started. The output file is "c:\temp\Logfiles\convert_log.txt"." that's it.

```
<#############################################################################################################################################################################################################
running powershell invisible#>
$window = Add-Type -memberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
"@ -name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
$window::ShowWindow((Get-Process –id $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0)

Start-Transcript -path "c:\temp\Logfiles\convert_log.txt" -NoClobber

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO

# Create a form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = ".doc to .docx converter"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380, 700)
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
#$Form.Icon            = 

# Create labels
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 20)
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 20)
$label1.Text = "Quellordner:"

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 80)
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280, 20)
$label2.Text = "Zielordner:"

# Create textboxes to display the selected folder paths
$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 50)
$textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$textBox1.ReadOnly = $true

$textBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 110)
$textBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
$textBox2.ReadOnly = $true

# Create button 1 to open the folder picker dialog for folder 1
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220, 50)
$button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$button1.Text = "Suche"
$button1.Add_Click({
    $folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $result = $folderBrowser.ShowDialog()
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $selectedFolder = $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
        $textBox1.Text = $selectedFolder
    }
})

# Create button 2 to open the folder picker dialog for folder 2
$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220, 110)
$button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$button2.Text = "Suche"
$button2.Add_Click({
    $folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $result = $folderBrowser.ShowDialog()
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $selectedFolder = $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
        $textBox2.Text = $selectedFolder
    }
})

# Create button 1 to clear the selected folder path for folder 1
$clearButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$clearButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300, 50)
$clearButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$clearButton1.Text = "Löschen"
$clearButton1.Add_Click({
    $textBox1.Text = ""
})

# Create button 2 to clear the selected folder path for folder 2
$clearButton2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$clearButton2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300, 110)
$clearButton2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
$clearButton2.Text = "Löschen"
$clearButton2.Add_Click({
    $textBox2.Text = ""
})

# Create the TextBox control
$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textbox.Multiline = $true
$textbox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 250)
$textbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 400)

# Function to append output to the textbox
function AppendToTextBox($text) {
    $textbox.AppendText("$text`r`n")
    $textbox.ScrollToCaret()
}

# Create a button to convert .doc files and move them to the new folder
$copyButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$copyButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 180)
$copyButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 30)
$copyButton.Text = "++ Konvertieren ++"
$copyButton.Add_Click({

    # Redirect output to the textbox
    $oldOut = [Console]::Out
    $outWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    [Console]::SetOut($outWriter)
    function Write-Host($text) {
        AppendToTextBox $text
    }

    $sourcePath = $textBox1.text
    $destinationPath = $textBox2.text
    $fileFormat = "*.docx"

    [ref]$SaveFormat = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type]
    $1word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $1word.Visible = $False

    $Path = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -Force | where{$_.Extension -eq ".doc"} 
    if($Path){
        forEach($EV in $Path) {
            Write-Host "Converting: $($EV.FullName)" -ForegroundColor Green
            [ref]$name = Join-Path -Path $EV.DirectoryName -ChildPath $($EV.BaseName + ".docx")
            $opendoc = $1word.documents.open($EV.FullName)
            $opendoc.saveas([ref]$name.Value, [ref]$saveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
            $opendoc.saveas([ref]$name.Value, [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
            $opendoc.close()
            $EV = $null
        }
    }

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter $fileFormat -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "~$*" }

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $destinationFile = $file.FullName.Replace($sourcePath, $destinationPath)
        $destinationDirectory = Split-Path -Path $destinationFile -Parent

        if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationDirectory)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationDirectory | Out-Null
        }

        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destinationFile
        Remove-Item -Path "$sourcePath\*~*.docx" -Force
    }

    $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File -Recurse

    foreach ($sourceFile in $sourceFiles) {
        $baseName = $sourceFile.BaseName

        $destinationFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -eq $baseName }

        if ($destinationFile) {
            $sourceMeta = Get-Item -Path $sourceFile.FullName

            $destinationFile.CreationTime = $sourceMeta.CreationTime
            $destinationFile.LastWriteTime = $sourceMeta.LastWriteTime
        }
    }

    # Restore output
    [Console]::SetOut($oldOut)
    $outWriter.Close()

    # Display the output in the textbox
    $output = $outWriter.ToString()
    AppendToTextBox $output

    $1word.Quit()
    $1word = $null
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    Write-Host "Abgeschlossen!" -ForegroundColor Green
})

Stop-Transcript

# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($label1)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1)
$form.Controls.Add($button1)
$form.Controls.Add($clearButton1)
$form.Controls.Add($label2)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2)
$form.Controls.Add($button2)
$form.Controls.Add($clearButton2)
$form.Controls.Add($copyButton)
$form.Controls.Add($textbox)

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```